# Calculate difference between 2 datetimes (Timespan + double)

Tags: c#, .net

I have a list that holds Datetimes.

To calculate the difference between 2 DateTime i use `TimeSpan`.

```
public static List<DateTime> list = new List<DateTime>();
TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan();
double result = 0;

ts = DateTime.Now - list[list.Count-1];
result = ts.TotalSeconds;
```

When debugging this code both the `DateTime.Now` and the `list[list.Count-1]` have DateTimes where the DateTime.Now is off course higher then the value of the list.

But for some reason i keep getting 0 in the variable result, how come exactly?

Best regards, Pete

Comment: This works just fine: http://ideone.com/2FViv

Comment: What value are you assigning to the `list`? In the above code it looks like it would be emtpy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tried the following, works perfectly okay.

```
            List<DateTime> list = new List<DateTime>();
            list.Add(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1));
            list.Add(DateTime.Now);
            list.Add(DateTime.Now.AddDays(1));
            TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan();
            double result = 0;

            ts = DateTime.Now - list[list.Count - 1];
            result = ts.TotalSeconds;
```

Attached the debbuging picture:

[image]

**Reasons for not working could be:**

1. Either your list is not being populated
2. Or the value of `ts.TotalSeconds` is smaller than double range (Which can be practically not possible.)

Answer (score 2):

First comment, you don't need `= new TimeSpan();` - you're only discarding this anyway when you set `ts` again further down.

What line is your debugger on when you see the value of 0 for `result`? Have you stepped **over** the line where `result` is set? If you are on the line, then that line has not yet actually run...

Comment: Ah  good catch, less new is good :). Ah it seems is have changed a value by accident in my if statement now the value is filling up correctly.

Comment: @PeterP, David M: Yes, it's better to get rid of ` = new TimeSpan()`, but it's probably not a big deal either way, since it will almost certainly be optimized into the same code, anyway, as `TimeSpan` is a struct, so it is zero-initialized by the CLR no matter what.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using 
     ts = DateTime.Now - list[list.Count-1];
use
     ts=DateTime.Now.Subtract(list[list.Count-1]

Answer (score 1):

I think time difference is to small for seconds, it might be in mili seconds or even smaller. Try ticks like this.

result = ts.Ticks;

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with the code you have posted (except I would suggest that you join declaration and initialization of your variables). I have to guess but perhaps you are "swallowing" exceptions and pass the empty list?

Then the line

```
ts = DateTime.Now - list[list.Count-1];
```

will throw an exception and `result` will retain it's value of `0`.

Answer (score 1):

list doesn't have any elements, so list.Count - 1 doesn't hit anything. also, there might not be an entire second to calculate. i added a time (using ticks) to subtract with. other than that, there's nothing wrong with what you have.

```
double result = 0;
List<DateTime> list = new List<DateTime>();
list.Add(new DateTime(123456));

TimeSpan ts = DateTime.Now - list[list.Count - 1];
result = ts.TotalSeconds;
```